# How to Drag and Drop(copy) from one panel to another panel

Tags: c#, vb.net, drag-and-drop

I have two panels on a form.
One panel has some controls like buttons or images and second panel is empty. I want to drag a control from panel 1 and drop it to panel 2, but it should create a copy of control, and while dragging a rectangle should be shown of same size as control and when dropped in panel 2 the dragged shape should appear there at mouse position
Actually I want to create a simulator like thing. That has some tools in panel 1 and when someone drag and drop a tool on panel 2 it should appear there at mouse position.

Language doesn't matter may be `C#` or `VB.NET`

Comment: Show some code what you did so far, please

Comment: Tell us what you've done, and what didn't work. There's lots of resources for drag and drop on the Internet. What have you searched for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like this ?

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    this.panel1.AllowDrop = true;  
    foreach (Control c in this.panel1.Controls)  
    {  
        c.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(c_MouseDown);  
    }  
    this.panel1.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragOver);  
    this.panel1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragDrop);  
}  

void c_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)  
{  
    Control c = sender as Control;  
    c.DoDragDrop(c, DragDropEffects.Move);  
}  

void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)  
{  
    Control c = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]) as Control;  
    if (c != null)  
    {  
        c.Location = this.panel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));  
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(c);  
    }  
}  

void panel1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)  
{  
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;  
}
```

VB.NET

```
Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.panel1.AllowDrop = True
    For Each c As Control In Me.panel1.Controls
        c.MouseDown += New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf c_MouseDown)
    Next
    Me.panel1.DragOver += New DragEventHandler(AddressOf panel1_DragOver)
    Me.panel1.DragDrop += New DragEventHandler(AddressOf panel1_DragDrop)
End Sub

Private Sub c_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim c As Control = TryCast(sender, Control)
    c.DoDragDrop(c, DragDropEffects.Move)
End Sub

Private Sub panel1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
    Dim c As Control = TryCast(e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()(0)), Control)
    If c IsNot Nothing Then
        c.Location = Me.panel1.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
        Me.panel1.Controls.Add(c)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub panel1_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
End Sub
```

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/3d23ad93-e70d-4076-bf50-3e17ec43d0e1)

Answer (score 2):

Am changing a little of code of @Shim. 
Here is the updated code in which a copy of your control will be placed in another panel

```
Random rnd = new Random();

private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    this.panel1.AllowDrop = true;  
    foreach (Control c in this.panel1.Controls)  
    {  
        c.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(c_MouseDown);  
    }  
    this.panel1.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragOver);  
    this.panel1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragDrop);  
}  

void c_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)  
{  
    Control c = sender as Control;  
    c.DoDragDrop(c, DragDropEffects.Move);  
}  

void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)  
{  
    Control c = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]) as Control;
    // Here, you get a copy of your drag drop button and dynamically new button is created  
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Name = "Button" + rnd.Next();
    btn.Size = c.Size;
    if (c != null)  
    {  
        // Add the newly created button to you Panel
        btn.Location = this.panel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));  
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(btn);  
    }  
}  

void panel1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)  
{  
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this solution will drag the button(or any other component selected) while moving the mouse and place it on the place where you drop it

```
private SimpleButton selectedButton;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        xtraScrollableControl2.AllowDrop = true;
        xtraScrollableControl2.DragEnter += XtraScrollableControl_DragEnter;
        xtraScrollableControl2.DragDrop += XtraScrollableControl_DragDrop;
        xtraScrollableControl2.DragOver += XtraScrollableControl_DragOver;
    }

    private void XtraScrollableControl_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Bitmap)) ? DragDropEffects.Copy : DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void XtraScrollableControl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        var simpleButton = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]) as SimpleButton;
        if (simpleButton == null) return;
        if (simpleButton.Parent != sender) 
        {
            var btn = new SimpleButton
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.None,
                Size = new Size(125, 50),
                Text = simpleButton.Text,
                Location = ((XtraScrollableControl) sender).PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)),
                ImageList = simpleButton.ImageList, 
                ImageIndex = simpleButton.ImageIndex,
                ImageLocation = simpleButton.ImageLocation,
                Parent = ((XtraScrollableControl)sender)
            };
            btn.MouseDown += simpleButton_MouseDown;

            ((XtraScrollableControl)sender).Controls.Add(btn);
        }
        else
        {
            ((XtraScrollableControl)sender).Controls.Remove(simpleButton);
            simpleButton.Location = ((XtraScrollableControl)sender).PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            ((XtraScrollableControl)sender).Controls.Add(simpleButton);
        }

        selectedButton = null;
    }

    private void XtraScrollableControl_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        selectedButton.Location = ((XtraScrollableControl)sender).PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }

    private void simpleButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = sender as SimpleButton;
        if (btn == null) return;
        selectedButton = btn;
        btn.DoDragDrop(btn, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
```

hope this will help some

i used DevExpress components
but for the standart

```
DevExpress
XtraScrollableControl
SimpleButton

Microsoft
Panel
Button
```